# Editing an old answer for which there is detail in comments

Tags: discussion, edits

I'm specifically talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0). The accepted answer is right, but it is quite succinct and doesn't provide an implementation of the solution. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0#comment36785879_356154), under the accepted answer, does. Should the accepted answer be edited to include this comment?

Comment: I wouldn't mess with very old highly upvoted content. But that question already has a huge pile of answers, surely one of them has the missing information?

Comment: Answers are served with comments. Talking about old answers, before current standards were rise high.

Comment: But comments can disappear at any time, right? If the info is vital/very helpful, surely it should be somewhere more 'permanent'?

Comment: I know you are asking for a specific question, but I've come across situations like this more than once, where well received answer have comments that contain just as important information, so I'm interested to know what the general policy for such edits would be.